# How to kill a process opened with open ()

Tags: windows, perl

I am trying to kill a process that I opened in background in Perl on Win32 (XP)
I tried several things.... not seems to be working....

```
$pid = open( CMD, "| cmd.exe > C:\\cmdout.txt" );
```

To Kill this background process tried several things....:(

1. `system('taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe');`
2. `system("taskkill /F /pid $pid");`
3. `close CMD || warn "cmd exited $?";`

Option 2 never works tried to print the values of PID  print and actual in system are different. 
Option 1 works but I feel that the process is still running in the back ground because after I end the process I wait for some time and re start the process...

Please help

-Thanks

Comment: That sounds like a Windows-specific question.

Comment: The original post said `system('taskkill /F /pid $pid')`.  I changed that to double quotes, because otherwise `$pid` wouldn't get interpolated.  I'm hoping that was just a typo in your post, and not the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played a bit with your case. Apparently two cmd.exe are started, parent with PID returned by `open` and its child doing commands.

Second scenario partially works, it kills the parent, but child remain running. Using `/T` option to `taskkill` you can force it to kill all children:

```
system("taskkill /F /T /pid $pid");
```

You will see message about termination of both processes:

```
SUCCESS: The process with PID 3956 child of PID 1864 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 1864 child of PID 580 has been terminated.
```

Third scenario seems to work fine for me. Closing the filehandle makes both CMD processes to die.

Comment: ahhh I totally forgot about the /T option. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you port to using [`Win32::Process`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aProcess) and use its process management support.