# How to hide following PID response :" SUCCESS: The process with PID 7652 (child process of PID 10272)" has been terminated from terminal using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, python-3.5

Python script is using Pyspark Library for data processing.
It  returns JSON filename along with following response on command prompt:

**1569861264384367000
**SUCCESS: The process with PID 7652 (child process of PID 10272) has been terminated.SUCCESS: The process with PID 10272 (child process of PID 9212) has been terminated.**

The file name is used as an input response to php script. Currently 
file name along with PID message gets displayed which unable PHP script to identify exact file name.

I require to hide or disable PID response from command prompt.

On running same Python script using Spyder I do not get any PID response like above.
What could be the probable reason of getting such error or warning message and How to hide or disable same?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4911366

Comment: Also i want the response of Python for php script. I give print statement which act as a response for php but currently i am getting print statement along with PID message. How to hide or disable PID response on command prompt?